# How to manipulate with the data in a cycle gnuplot 4.6

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I would like to plot several lines in a gnuplot (version 4.6 or 5.0) using loop and during plotting manipulate with the data. 
For simple plotting of the data (without manipulation) i use

`plot for [i=2:100] 'data.dat' u 1:i with lines lt 1 lc rgb 'blue' notitle`
and everything is fine: [Normal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pheH1.png)

but!

when i'm trying to manipulate with data in this code:

`plot for [i=2:100] 'data.dat' u 1:(i-0.3) with lines lt 1 lc rgb 'blue'`

the gnuplot resist to my manipulation and gives the strange result:
[The strange result after the second code and assumptions to manipulate on the date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zqcx.png). Also I've tried ($i-0.3) instead of (i-0.3) and also without brackets, all this doesn't work. Could anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `using 1:(column(i) - 0.3)`

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I passed the whole day looking for the solution! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `column(i)` to access a column's value for calculation, if the column number is given by a variable `i`:

```
plot for [i=2:100] 'data.dat' u 1:(column(i)-0.3)
```